# list view on relative layout didn't show

Tags: android-listview, android-studio, sms

activity_sms.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >   
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/SMSList"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

code on SMSActivity.java

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms);
        smsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SMSList);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smsMessagesList);
        smsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        smsListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

code on fragment_1.java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sms, container, false);

        return rootView;
```

I tried to make a program to read SMS from inbox and show it on a ListView. It works when SMSActivity is the only activity there 
Now, I use MainActivity.java instead of SMSActivity.java as Main Activity. 
My goal is to invoke SMSActivity.java using fragment. 
If anyone can help me it would be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you want to show in your layout?For example you have some items like this

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_title"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_details"
        android:text="@string/description"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In ths case you can set the value for this items in your adapter

```
    @Override
    public View getView (int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.linear_big_list_item, parent, false);
    TextView nameOfItem = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_title);
    TextView descriptionOfItem = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_details);
    return view;
}
```